# Using DECODE Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, decode

I have been trying to learn SQL, and I was learning the DECODE statement:

This is the query I was trying to use:

```
SELECT DECODE(FIRST_NAME,'Steven','Name is Steven','Neena','Name is Neena','Some other name') AS "NAME" FROM hr.employees;
```

This query works successfully,but when I try the query:

```
SELECT DECODE(FIRST_NAME,'Steven','Name is Steven','Neena','Name is Neena','Some other name') AS "NAME" WHERE FIRST_NAME='Steven' FROM hr.employees;
```

This query gives me the output as:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Can anyone explain me what's wrong?

Comment: WHERE  goes after FROM.

Comment: ... as shown [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDDCHGF), and nothing to do with the decode.

Answer (score -1):

`Where` clause needs to be placed after `From` clause.

```
SELECT DECODE(FIRST_NAME,'Steven','Name is Steven','Neena','Name is Neena','Some other name') AS "NAME"  
FROM hr.employees
WHERE FIRST_NAME='Steven';
```

Comment: Please accept this as answer if it helped you.